# foreach inside IF condition will not output, even when condition is TRUE

Tags: php, xml, if-statement, foreach, conditional-statements

I've looked at this too long to be able to discern why it's not working. As stated in the comments of the sample file (link below) I can output the correct values for the variables used in the IF condition. But as soon as I wrap the foreach in the condition, followed by the ELSE, the condition is ignored and the ELSE statement is output.

I have tested this replacing either/both of the two IF variables with numbers. It works correctly in that case. But when it's the two variables, it won't. I am baffled and convinced it's something entirely basic and likely syntax which I'm blind to because I've tried to find it too many times ... I hope.

PHP: https://pastebin.com/2ZGTPjs0

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

$expenseCount = $xml->EXP->count();
$grandTotal = $xml->GRANDTOTAL;
$annualMax = $xml->ANNUALMAX;

// xPath is correct. The below test outputs the correct numbers.
// echo "<h1>GRAND TOTAL: ".$grandTotal."</h1><br/><h1>ANNUAL MAX: ".$annualMax."</h1>";

// The below if condition seems to be ignored and I can't figure out why!!
// Even though $grandTotal IS GREATER THAN $annualMax, the else statement
if ($grandTotal > $annualMax) {

foreach($xml->EXP as $expenses) {

echo "<div class=\"coupon ".$i."\">";
echo "<h1>Reimbursement</h1><h2>Coupon No. ".$i." of ".$expenseCount."</h2>";

echo "<table>
<tbody>
<tr class=\"headings\">
<th>Service</th>
<th>Vendor</th>
<th>Date of Service</th>
<th>Reason</th>
<th>Total Cost</th>
<th>Amount Paid</th>
<th>Balance Due</th>
</tr>";
echo "<tr class=\"expense-details\">";
echo "<td>".$expenses->SERVICE."</td>";
echo "<td>".$expenses->VENDOR."</td>";
$serviceDate = date('M d, Y', strtotime($expenses->DATE));
echo "<td>".$serviceDate."</td>";
echo "<td>".$expenses->REASON."</td>";
echo "<td>$".$expenses->COST."</td>";
echo "<td>$".$expenses->PAID."</td>";
echo "<td>$".$expenses->BALANCE."</td>";
echo "</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";

echo "</div>";

$i++;
}
} else {
echo "<div class=\"not-yet\">";
echo "<h1>Your current total is $".$grandTotal.". You have not exceeded the annual minimum out-of-pocket expenses of $".$annualMax.".</h1>";
echo "</div>";
}
```

XML: https://pastebin.com/3Md8w93J

```
<EXPREP>
<GRANDTOTAL>727.94</GRANDTOTAL>
<ANNUALMAX>714</ANNUALMAX>
<EXP>
<DATE>Fri Jan 12 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</DATE>
<SERVICE>Repair</SERVICE>
<VENDOR>ABC Auto Body</VENDOR>
<REASON>Out of Alignment</REASON>
<COST>130</COST>
<PAID>110</PAID>
<BALANCE>20</BALANCE>
</EXP>
<EXP>
<DATE>Tue Jan 23 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</DATE>
<SERVICE>Repair</SERVICE>
<VENDOR>XYZ Gas Station</VENDOR>
<REASON>Travel Gas</REASON>
<COST>212</COST>
<PAID>192</PAID>
<BALANCE>20</BALANCE>
</EXP>
<EXP>
<DATE>Tue Jan 23 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</DATE>
<SERVICE>Radiator Flush</SERVICE>
<VENDOR>Quick Flush</VENDOR>
<REASON>Annual Radiator Maintenance</REASON>
<COST>101.12</COST>
<PAID>91.12</PAID>
<BALANCE>10</BALANCE>
</EXP>
<EXP>
<DATE>Fri Jan 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</DATE>
<SERVICE>Oil Change</SERVICE>
<VENDOR>ABC Auto Body</VENDOR>
<REASON>3000 Mile Oil Change</REASON>
<COST>125</COST>
<PAID>105</PAID>
<BALANCE>20</BALANCE>
</EXP>
</EXPREP>
```

Pastebins are up for a week.

Comment: Don't use pastebins. Include relevant material in your question so that it remains meaningful for people looking for similar answers in the future.

Comment: I used pastebins because they have a raw view which accommodates the php open / close tags and is easy to copy / paste. Also note that I DID include the relevant material in the body of the question ...

Comment: Not directly relevant, but this is not the way to produce lexical XML output. You are making no attempt to escape special characters appearing in the data, so you will produce invalid XML as soon as your data contains `&` or `<`.

Comment: @MichaelKay While I appreciate the concern, this isn't really about producing XML output. It's about using an XML data source in PHP. That said, the XML output is generated by a Google Apps Script which converts the rows and columns of a Google Sheet into valid XML. Just tested your concern and it properly encodes html entities in the node content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try casting the variables to a float. As it stands they are SimpleXML objects which is probably messing up your comparison:

`$grandTotal = (float) $xml->GRANDTOTAL;
 $annualMax = (float) $xml->ANNUALMAX;`

Comment: SO grateful. Thank you.